# Camel does not set 'Transfer-Encoding chunked' in case response is prepared by exception handler processor

Tags: rest, apache-camel, cxf, soapui, restful-architecture

I am implementing REST services using Apache-CXF running on servicemix and for that I have a camel route that does some processing, sends the message over queue, process some more and send back the reply. Something like this:

```
from("direct:start")
    .process(A)
    .process("activemq:abc")
    .process(B);
```

On this route I have applied some basic validation and exception handler and when I have to stop the route in both cases, I use something like this:

```
exchange.getOut().setBody(response);
exchange.setProperty(Exchange.ROUTE_STOP, Boolean.TRUE);
```

I use soap UI, restclient-UI and putty to make http requests and I get proper response body displayed in all of them. Now I wanted to preserve request headers so I made a little change everywhere in the code so that response bodies are set in exchange.getIn() only. For example: in case of validation failure I do:

```
exchange.getIn().setBody(response);
exchange.setProperty(Exchange.ROUTE_STOP, Boolean.TRUE);
```

Just with this little change, the rest clients I am using to make request **stopped displaying the response body**. As per the server logs, response is being generated and also as per the logs in rest client, I am getting the proper response but **they are unable to display the response body only in case when I stop the route in between**. Normal response is displaying just fine. Only the restclient-UI was considerate enough to show the error as to why they are not displaying body and the error is:

```
Byte array conversion from response body stream failed.
```

Diggin deeper, I found the only response header which was there in success response but missing in error response:

```
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
```

Error response is around 1000 characters long and contains a header called content-length. I am not sure but I think the problem has something to do with this itself. I would really like to play with exchange.getIn but these different kind of responses prepared by camel are confusing me. How can I make sure my camel responses are always displayed properly?

Comment: It's possible that the content-length header is still present from the original HTTP request and because it's a different sized body in the response then it can't read the whole body on the Rest Client. Try removing the ContentLength header when you stop the exchange processing and let CXF put the correct length on the response.

Comment: You are right, Content-length header was the culprit. It is strange that camel has no handling at all for this thing. In order to keep original headers intact, i was working on exchange.getIn() only and that is where it remained inside the exchange. You can create an answer for this and i will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Content-Length header will be preserved from the original request so you need to remove it so that camel cxf can work out the new body length on the response and set Content-Length with that.

Comment: To counter this, we can remove the content-length header in our route like this:
<camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
      <from uri="jetty://http://myhost:9000/myservice/"/>
 <!-- remove the header of Content-Length -->
 <removeHeader headerName="Content-Length" />
      <to uri="otherEndpoint"/>
    </route>
  </camelContext>